# Generate POCO-s in EF Code First from an existing database?

Tags: sql-server-2005, .net-4.0, entity-framework-4

Is this possible? I have about 40 existing databases with the same structure to which i'd prefer not to manually write out the entity classes nor use the .edmx file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can install the [Entity Framework Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d) Visual Studio extension and then use the Reverse Engineer Code First option.

Answer (score 0):

EFDesigner in VS2012 by default generates POCO. In VS2010 you can use [EF 4.x DbContext Generator](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7812b04c-db36-4817-8a84-e73c452410a2)